# F# Giraffe: Different cache headers based on result

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

I am struggling with how to set different cache response headers based on whether the result is an Ok or an Error. My code is something like the following (but with other types in the result):

```
let resultToJson (result:Result<'a,string>) : HttpHandler = 
    match result with
    | Ok o -> Successful.ok (json o)
    | Error s -> ServerErrors.internalError (text s)
```

I can add the headers by doing something like the following:

```
let resultToJson (result:Result<'a,string>) : HttpHandler = 
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
        let response =
            let headers = ctx.Response.Headers
            match result with
            | Ok o ->
                headers.Add("Cache-Control", new StringValues("public, max-age=10, stale-while-revalidate=2"))
                headers.Add("Vary", new StringValues("Origin"))
                Successful.ok (json o)
            | Error s -> 
                headers.Add("Cache-Control", new StringValues("no-cache"))
                ServerErrors.internalError (text s)
        response next ctx
```

But this does not feel right. I would like to use the standard HttpHandlers from the ResponseCaching module to set the right cache headers:

```
publicResponseCaching 10 (Some "Origin") // For Ok: Add 10 sec public cache, Vary by Origin
noResponseCaching // For Error: no caching
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't have a Giraffe project ready to test this, so just an idea - both your `resultToJson` and those caching functions are `HttpHandler`s, so you should be able to extend your first snippet like `| Ok o -> Successful.ok (json o) >=> publicResponseCaching 10 (Some "Origin")` (and `>=> noResponseCaching` for the error case)

Answer (score 0):

The  [response cache handler](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#response-caching) is supposed to be piped into an normal pipeline. Your choice between `Ok` and `Error` is a choose function, so you can use a choose that takes a list of handlers that can be attempted. To reject a path, just return a `task { return None }`, to move forward, it's `next ctx`.

If you want to keep all the logic in one controller, like you have now, just keep your match and pipe your json/text response into one of the caching handlers.

`let fn = json o >=> publicResponseCaching 30 None) in fn next ctx`

if it's nested inside a hander, instead of in a pipeline, you have to apply the `next` & `ctx`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

Yes, I can chain the HttpHandlers like Gerard and Honza Brestan mentioned, using the fish operator (`>=>`). The reason I could not make that work in the first place was that I also had created a fish operator for the `Result` type in an opened module. Basically I had created proper **fish soup**

As soon as I refactored my code so that the module containing the `Result` fish operator was not open in this scope, everything worked fine as expected.

Another point to remember is that response caching needs to be called *before* the finalizing HttpHandler, otherwise it will not be called:

```
// Simplified code
let resultToJson =
    function
    | Ok o -> publicResponseCaching 10 (Some "Origin") >=> Successful.ok(json o)
    | Error e -> noResponseCaching >=> ServerErrors.internalError(text e)
```